# ng-routes not working in ng-view

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui, ngroute

I am try to use ng-routes in my application for the first time. In the examples though they looked very simple but now when I am trying to implement they are not giving expected result. I am using angular with onsen ui. 
Basically the problem is I am not able to see content of my partial templates on my main page and the url is getting changed as expected.

```
<body id="Android" ng-app="hybrid-android"
ng-controller="androidController">
<ons-template id="menu.html"> <ons-page
    modifier="menu-page"> <ons-toolbar modifier="transparent">
<div class="right">
    <ons-toolbar-button class="menu-closeMenu" ng-click="menu.closeMenu()">
    </ons-icon>Close </ons-toolbar-button>
</div>
</ons-toolbar> <ons-list class="menu-list"> <ons-list-item
    class="menu-item"> <ons-icon icon="fa-plus"></ons-icon>
<a href="#red">Profile</a> </ons-list-item> <ons-list-item class="menu-item">
<ons-icon icon="fa-bookmark"></ons-icon> <a href="#yellow">Change
    password</a> </ons-list-item> <ons-list-item class="menu-item"> <ons-icon
    icon="fa-twitter"></ons-icon> <a href="#blue">logOut</a> </ons-list-item> </ons-list> <br>
  <div>
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</div></ons-template>
```

controller.js

```
 ///<reference path="angular.min.js" />
var myApp = angular.module('hybrid-android',['onsen','ngRoute']);

myApp.controller('androidController', ['$scope', '$location' ,function($scope,$location) {

myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/red", {
        templateUrl : "profile.html"
    })
    .when("/yellow", {
        templateUrl : "changePassword.html"
    })
    .when("/blue", {
        templateUrl : "faq.html"
    });
});     
}]);
```

profile.html

```
<h1>PROFILE PAGE</h1>
```

changePassword.html

```
<h1>Change Password</h1>
```

Comment: Where is your ng-view in your view ?

Comment: @GeraldChablowski actually I added this view in another div.... Now have included that in this code too.. you can find that in last